# I have been recently getting an error from macOS "cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified." when I run my backend service

Tags: python, macos, flask, backend

> The error has been resolved for now : for future purposes:  I
> installed the grpcio manually using pip which led me to an error
> suggesting that I had a corrupted python framework, I uninstalled and
> reinstalled python again and poetry.

This particular thread was helpful: https://gist.github.com/MuhsinFatih/ee0154199803babb449b5bb98d3475f7

My MacOS version : 13.0 Beta

I have been getting this error when I enter the command : PYTHONPATH=. poetry run python services/tokenkeep/src/app.py  to run my backend service.

I get this pop up and there are a couple of popups like these that come repeatedly with different file names such as this:

> “cimmutabledict.cpython-39-darwin.so” cannot be opened because the
> developer cannot be verified.

If I move it to bin or cancel the pop ups I get a traceback which gives me an import error :

> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Users/khawajajunaid/Desktop/backend-python/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so,
> 0x0002): tried:
> '/Users/khawajajunaid/Desktop/backend-python/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (code signature in <2ED718E3-F901-35F5-968B-F85967D9BE12>
> '/Users/khawajajunaid/Desktop/backend-python/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> not valid for use in process: library load disallowed by system
> policy),
> '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/khawajajunaid/Desktop/backend-python/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (no such file),
> '/Users/khawajajunaid/Desktop/backend-python/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (code signature in <2ED718E3-F901-35F5-968B-F85967D9BE12>
> '/Users/khawajajunaid/Desktop/backend-python/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> not valid for use in process: library load disallowed by system
> policy)

I have tried installing poetry again, updating the packages and deleting my local repo and pulling the repo again, setting up the virtual environment but nothing has bore me fruit.

It was working fine with the same setup and messed up after I ran poetry install since I couldn't see my lock file in the service directory, would really appreciate some help, its been holding up my whole service.

Comment: disable signature verification for workaround ? https://www.imore.com/how-open-apps-anywhere-macos-catalina-and-mojave -- another approach would be that you compile everything yourself with your local xcode ..

Comment: Thank you, I reinstalled everything and it went away perhaps there was a problem due to an error in the python framework